# Python to run JavaScript function with two parameters

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait

There is a link

```
<a href="javascript:ga_and_go('//weathernews.jp/s/topics/?fm=onebox', 'topics_more')">…もっと見る</a>
```

in a html page, I want to click it, I tried code as below, it seems like page can't be parsed, how can I run that function `ga_and_go('//weathernews.jp/s/topics/?fm=onebox', 'topics_more')`:

```
more_button = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("…もっと見る")
more_button.click()
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or it just isn't doing anything?

Comment: Is that the same as `driver.execute_script("ga_and_go('//weathernews.jp/s/topics/?fm=onebox', 'topics_more')")`?

Comment: No, that would be used by the page's javascript in a way that you wouldn't be able to mimic unless you had access to the underlying javascript library

Comment: But I got what I need after execute script.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the below xpath to click the element?

`//a[contains(@href,'javascript:ga_and_go(')]`

```
more_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'javascript:ga_and_go(')]")
more_button.click()
```

Comment: I got error `SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains(@href,'javascript:ga_and_go('//weathernews.jp/s/topics')]' is not a valid XPath expression.`

Comment: yes, got it. You should have commented the second single apostrophe. However, Could you please use this xpath: //a[contains(@href,'javascript:ga_and_go(')]

Comment: @mikezang, did you get a chance to try with this xpath: : `//a[contains(@href,'javascript:ga_and_go(')]` ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML the element seems to be *JavaScript* based so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "もっと見る"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'もっと見る')]"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```